# Angular: NgClass - Grouping conditions

Tags: angular, ng-class

Is there a way to simplify this ngClass?

- `edit` ? - This one works fine
- `value ===` - This is a child component. Each of the two parent components pass the `value` property down as an @Input. Child component 1 has a `released` property. Child component 2 does not have the `released` property.
- If the `value` is `value1` AND the `released` property is `true`, no class is added. However, if the `released` property is `false` add a class called `class-3`.
- If the `value` is `value2`, always add `class-3` as there is no `released` property.

The below works, but it feels like it could be streamlined.

```
<div [ngClass]="[
 edit ? 'class-1' : 'class-2',
 value === 'value1' && released ? '' : 'class-3',
 value === 'value2' ? 'class-3' : ''
]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimise a part of it by moving to [class], much shorter and concise:

```
<div [class.class-3]="(value === 'value1' && !released) || value === 'value2'"
... /the rest of the ngClass for edit
</div>
```

or keep it all in ngClasse. It can be also shorter:

```
<div [ngClass]="[
 edit ? 'class-1' : 'class-2',
 released ? value != 'value1' || value==='value2'? : 'class-3' : ''
]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You really have a complex condition out there, this is the best I can think of:

```html
<div
  [ngClass]="{
    'class-1': edit,
    'class-2': !edit,
    'class-3': value === 'value2' || (value === 'value1' && !released)
  }"
></div>
```